# Typeorm get relations for array column of ids

Tags: postgresql, typeorm

I am looking to add a column of `id`'s to `Invoice` with the items from the invoice.

I'm getting the error

> Entity metadata for Invoice#invoiceItems was not found.

I've tried these two options:

```
class Invoice {

  @OneToMany(type => InvoiceItem, invoiceItem => invoiceItem.id)
  @JoinColumn()
  invoiceItems: InvoiceItem[]
  @RelationId((self: Invoice) => self.invoiceItems)
  invoiceItemIds: number[]

}
```

and

```
class Invoice {

  @OneToMany(type => InvoiceItem, invoiceItem => invoiceItem.id)
  @JoinColumn()
  invoiceItems: InvoiceItem[]
  @Column({ type: PostgresColumns.number, array: true, nullable: false, default: {} })
  invoiceItemIds: number[]
```

How can I add relations for an array of ids?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use @JoinColumn for @OneToMany (see the [docs](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/src/decorator/relations/JoinColumn.ts)), you need to configure that in your InvoiceItem class:

```
@Entity()
class Invoice { 
    @OneToMany(type => InvoiceItem, invoiceItem => invoiceItem.invoice) 
    invoiceItems: InvoiceItem[];

    @RelationId((self: Invoice) => self.invoiceItems) 
    invoiceItemIds: number[] 
}

@Entity()
class InvoiceItem { 
    ...
    @ManyToOne(type => Invoice, invoice => invoice.invoiceItems) 
    invoice: Invoice;
    ...
}
```

I haven't worked with @RelationId yet, but if you correctly join the InvoiceItems this should work.